# Moving Window Average Convolution with different Radii - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to perform a basic moving average convolution of an array where each pixel is replaced by the average of its surrounding pixels.

But my problem scenario goes like this :

- I have two arrays **valueArray** and **radiiArray**. Both the arrays have the same shape.
- I need to apply the moving average to the **valueArray** but instead of having a constant radius to get my neighboring pixels, I want each pixel's average be calculated with a different radii - values of which are stored in the **radiiArray**

I could implement it using *for loops* but that would be time consuming since the arrays are too large. Is this possible using the numpy library?

Comment: Give us a simple example using loops.  It is easier to test and explain ideas with your case(s).  Is it 1d, 2d?  Overlapping windows?

Comment: `as_strided`was mentioned for another moving window case today, but probably won't work with varying radii.  `np.sum.reduceat` has some possiblilites.  `dot` product of your data with a `weight` vectors is another possibility (`scipy sparse implements `sum` with a matrix product).

Comment: The arrays are 2d and there are overlapping windows since neighboring average is being take of each pixel.

Comment: With 2d you many have to dig into imaging modules.  I don't there's any magic in `numpy`.

Comment: I searched around but there aren't any imaging modules that performs the above task. Can anyone specify a module that could do the above convolution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting a rather customized moving window average convolution, it is unlikely that you will find it in an existing library.

Instead you can implement this in a straightforward way with loops. Then use Cython, f2py or numba, etc to speed this up to a level comparable with a native C/Fortran implementation, while still using numpy to access and store data in memory.